# C#: Using async on a post API

Tags: c#, api, post, async-await, task

Created a POST API which basically save a file in one directory.

Will asynchronous code make my API better at handling the scalability when multiple requests come from clients?

Currently, the code works synchronously.

Should I make every method as asynchronous? And where should I place the keyword await?

The tasks:

Task 1: Read request content (XML)

Task 2: Create a directory if not created already

Task 3: Uniquely make filenames unique

Save file on the directory

```
  [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            string contentResult = string.Empty;
            ValidateRequest(ref contentResult, request);
            //contentResult = "nothing";
            //Validation of the post-requested XML 
            //XmlReaderSettings(contentResult);
           
            using (StringReader s = new StringReader(contentResult))
            {
                doc.Load(s);
            }

            string path = MessagePath;

            //Directory creation
            DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory($@"{path}\PostRequests");
            
            string dirName = dir.Name;

            //Format file name
            var uniqueFileName = UniqueFileNameFormat();

            doc.Save($@"{path}\{dirName}\{uniqueFileName}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogService.LogToEventLog($"Error occured while receiving a message from messagedistributor: " + e.ToString(), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            throw e;
        }
        LogService.LogToEventLog($"Message is received sucessfully from messagedistributor: ", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
        return new ResponseMessageResult(Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)200));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should.

When you use async with a network or IO calls, you do not block threads and they can be reused for processing other requests.
But, if you have only one drive and other clients do the the same job - you will not get speed benefits, but whole system health still would be better with async calls.

Comment: I have updated my question. How can I make the tasks async in which they are depended on each other ?

Comment: You will not get speed benefits with async/await period, unless the system experiences thread exhaustion.  Implying that async/await provides latency improvements may not have been your intent, but that is how it reads.

Comment: @DavidL So what you are saying is that I should not change this solution into an async solution on each task I listed above? I just read that async will suits for APIs that’s why it came to my mind changing the code to async

Comment: @Motivizer not at all.  However, it is important to understand that on a *per call basis*, latency will increase by a tiny (and perhaps unnoticeable amount) due to how async state machines are created.  That said, what you gain is considerable *throughput* benefits throughout your application and both your application and the underlying system will be much healthier as load is applied to your api.

Comment: Okay, thx for the response. My intention is to use an async API that handles huge amount of throughput for handling requests one by one. I am using WebSurge for load test and it seems that it takes to long for some api call. When i make a load test with two threads which runs simultaneously, I get errors on that the process is used by another. Should async not handle this kind of error?

Comment: @Motivizer, again if your API works with drive or network to do job, async is better. For example for handling 100 simultaneous API calls without async, you have to start 100 threads. With async it will start approx 5 - 10 threads and sever will not die so quick.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and the example of how sync vs async handles throughout respectively. One thing I do not understand is that when I use WebSurge for load testing. I make post calls for example 5 seconds with 2 threads that runs simultaneously. Does that 2 threads do the same job cause when it hits in code for saving a file, I get an error. It says that the file is used by another process? How can that even occur when I have async methods?

Comment: You have this error because two threads are trying to do the same job. One thread opened file for write, and second also trying to open the same file. Here you need a way to do not allow two threads open the same file simultaneously. But this not part of this question.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. I appreciate your input!